# Is it possible to pick data from SQL in a Lua code?

Tags: sql, lua, coronasdk

I'm coding with Solar2d in Lua and I wanted to pick data from an SQL table.
So I was thinking to use the *sqlite3* plugin, but it's unclear how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Solar2D has built-in SQLite library.
Check the documentation [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/sqlite3/index.html).
To pick data use `SELECT` with `db:nrows(sqlcommand)`